# Searching for strings in a text file

Tags: java

I was programing in Python but now I want to do the same code in Java. Can you help me please? This is the code that I was working on

```
import random
import re

a = "y"

while a == "y":   
 i = input('Search: ') 
 b = i.lower()
 word2 = ""
 for letter in b:
  lista = []  
  with open('d:\lista.txt', 'r') as inF: 
   for item in inF: 
    if item.startswith(letter):
        lista.append(item)
   word = random.choice(lista)
   word2 = word2 + word 

 print(word2)

 a = input("Again? ")
```

Now I want to do the same on Java but Im not really sure how to do it. Its not that easy. Im just a beginner. So far I founded a code that makes the search in a text file but I'm stuck.

This is the java code. It finds the position of the word. I've been trying to modify it without the results Im looking for.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class test {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Search: ");
    String searchText = input.nextLine(); 
    String fileName = "lista.txt"; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));


        while (reader.ready()) {

            sb.append(reader.readLine());
        }

    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    String fileText = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("Position in file : " + fileText.indexOf(searchText));

}
}
```

What I want is  to find an item in a text file, a list, but just want to show the items that begin with the letters of the string I want to search. For example, I have the string "urgent" and the text file contains:
    baby
    redman
    love
    urban
    gentleman
    game
    elephant
    night
    todd
So the display would be "urban"+"redman"+"gentleman"+ until it reaches the end of the string.

Comment: Post your Java code so far, and where the issue specifically is.

Comment: Your Java code is working for me, so what is the problem? If you just tell me what you want I can give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you've already tokenized the string so you've got a list of Strings, each containing a single word. It's what comes from the reader if you've got one word per line, which is how your Python code is written.

```
String[] haystack = {"baby", "redman", "love", "urban", "gentleman", "game", 
    "elephant", "night", "todd"};
```

Now, to search for a needle, you can simply compare the first characters of your haystack to all characters of the needle :

```
String needle = "urgent";

for (String s : haystack) {
    for (int i = 0; i < needle.length(); ++i) {
        if (s.charAt(0) == needle.charAt(i)) {
            System.out.println(s);
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

This solutions runs in O(|needle| * |haystack|).
To improve it a bit for the cost of a little bit of extra memory, we can precompute a hash table for the available starts :

```
String needle = "urgent";
Set<Character> lookup = new HashSet<Character>();

for (int i = 0; i < needle.length(); ++i) {
        lookup.add(needle.charAt(i));         
}

for (String s : haystack) {
    if (lookup.contains(s.charAt(0))) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

The second solution runs in O(|needle| + |haystack|).

Answer (score 0):

This works if your list of words isn't too large. If your list of words is large you could adapt this so that you stream over the file multiple time collecting words to use.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;


public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Character, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Character, List<String>>();
        File file = new File("./lista.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // assumes words are space separated with no
                // quotes or commas
                String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

                for(String word : tokens) {
                    if(word.length() == 0) continue;

                    // might as well avoid case issues
                    word = word.toLowerCase();

                    Character firstLetter = Character.valueOf(word.charAt(0));

                    List<String> wordsThatStartWith = map.get(firstLetter);
                    if(wordsThatStartWith == null) {
                        wordsThatStartWith = new ArrayList<String>();
                        map.put(firstLetter, wordsThatStartWith);
                    }

                    wordsThatStartWith.add(word);
                }

            }

            Random rand = new Random();
            String test = "urgent";

            List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
                Character key = Character.valueOf(test.charAt(i));
                List<String> wordsThatStartWith = map.get(key);
                if(wordsThatStartWith != null){
                    String randomWord = wordsThatStartWith.get(rand.nextInt(wordsThatStartWith.size()));
                    words.add(randomWord);
                } else {
                    // text file didn't contain any words that start
                    // with this letter, need to handle
                }
            }

            for(String w : words) {
                System.out.println(w);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes the content of lista.txt looks like

```
baby redman love urban gentleman game elephant night todd
```

And the output will look something like

```
urban
redman
gentleman
elephant
night
todd
```